# ReactNative - Text being cut off in repeating list of results on customer's android phone

Tags: react-native

I am noticing the following code in ReactNative (React 0.59), which represents a single search result item, is sometimes cutting off the last line of text on a client's android phone (but not on any of my android phones or simulators)

```
<View style={this.props.style}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'  }}>
           <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
             {this.itemSentences()}
           </Text>
          </View>
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, marginTop: -7}}>
          <Text style={{color: '#000', fontSize: ellipsisFontSize, fontWeight: '600'}}>{ellipsisText}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

In the image below, you can see the effect, which is an incomplete sentence being rendered:

[image: Result with the 3rd item (starts with 426) being cut off]

It almost looks like there isn't enough room to render the rest of the text, so it cuts it off. Again, on my phone, it renders the whole paragraph but in the client's screen shot, it is cut off.

Any initial suggestions or things I can do? I tried reducing the font, increasing the font, changing padding, but no luck. What other details can I provide? Thank you!

Edit:
Here is the container the above list items appear in:

```
<View style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <FlatList
        onContentSizeChange={ (x, y) => { this.layoutChanged(x, y) } }
        onLayout={(event) => this.layoutChanged(event)}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        data={dataSource}
        ListFooterComponent={footer}
        ListHeaderComponent={header}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)}
        language={this.props.language}
        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
      />
        <AnimatedEditedResults 
          style={[editResultsStyle, {transform: [{translateX: this.state.editResultsOverlayX}]}]}
          editResultsXButtonPressed={this.hideEditResultsOverlay.bind(this)}
          applyFilterPressed={this.applyFilterPressed.bind(this)}
          searchResults={this.props.originalSearchResults.Results}
          selectedSources={this.props.selectedSources}
          sentenceNumber={this.props.sentenceNumber}
          hasMadeChanges={this.props.hasMadeChanges}
          clearFilterPressed={this.props.clearFilterPressed}
          language={this.props.language}
        />
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with over 100+ different kinds of builds, different attempts, etc. I finally found the issue.

There is a property on  called "TextBreakStyle" and by default it is "complex". By changing to "Simple", the issue went away. This apparently only plagues certain types of phones/devices.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you cant wrap the component in a ScrollView

Comment: The items above are within a <FlatList>. Are you saying within the flatlist, each element that appears can be in a scrollview? Are there any other containers I could use that would hold the text and enforce it to render everything rather than cut off? Are there any properties of FlatList, perhaps, that are truncating each element above within to a certain height? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Adam I also just pasted my <FlatList> code above - anything unusual about it that would cause certain elements to be cut off?

Comment: i didnt realise it was in a flatlist so it should scroll, there is still a lot of missing info so icant say for sure but one thing that could cause it is the keys.  can you rather use id's or a unique attribute rather than the index,  using index can cause unexpected behaviour